# How to Run sencha touch program in android avd?

Tags: touch, extjs

In sencha touch, i built simple hello word program. it is working fine with browser but i don't no how to run this program in android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 2 ways to do this:

1. Build your app as native Android app using Phonegap. Detailed instructions are provided at: http://phonegap.com/start#android
2. If you're using Sencha Touch 2, you can use it's build-in native Android packaging via Sencha SDK. See this: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android